# Upgrading Rails: rails new . creating a new directory new in the project folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to upgrade rails from 2.3 to 3.1. I have referred the upgrade video from rails cast but i am having some difficulties.

```
Steps i have followed till now.
1. Create a separate rails-3 branch from stable branch.
2. Update & reload rvm to the latest version.
3. gem install rails -v 3.0.20
4. rails upgrade check and rails upgrade backup using rails upgrade plugin
5. rails new .
```

**The step 5 is where i am facing issue** this is creating a separate application in a folder named "new" in a sub directory and this is not over writing the current application as per the video in rails cast.

**When i am checking the rails version after installing rails gem in step 3 i still see the rails version as 2.3.18.**

Can anyone please help. What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what does `rails --version` say? I suspect it's v2 running. You need v3.

Comment: hi sergio, it says Rails 2.3.18

Comment: is there any step i missed or did not follow correctly. i see the rails version as 2.3.18

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, i had to delete the Gemfile.lock and the issue got resolved.